# Firebase when receive Push Notification did not receive the popup

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    registerForPushNotifications(application)
    FIRApp.configure()

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NSNotificationCenter
     .defaultCenter()
     .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.tokenRefreshNotificaiton),
                                                     name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
  }

func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
  }


  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("===== didReceiveRemoteNotification ===== %@", userInfo)
  }


 func tokenRefreshNotificaiton(notification: NSNotification) {
    let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
     connectToFcm()
  }

  func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
      if (error != nil) {
        print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
      } else {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
      }
    }
  }
```

Also to done in Info.plist FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO

I don't know for now but I got the print(...) in didReceiveRemoteNotification but don't get the popup. I send the message from Firebase -> Console -> Notification -> Single device and copy here the token which I got from xCode Console -> func tokenRefreshNotificaiton

Get the next in console, but don't get popup

```
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
InstanceID token: TOKEN_ID
Connected to FCM.
===== didReceiveRemoteNotification ===== %@ [notification: {
    body = test;
    e = 1;
}, collapse_key: com.pf.app, from: 178653764278]
```

Also app configurations
[image]

Comment: Possible solution :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538330/fcm-notification-is-not-working-in-ios/38093732#38093732

Comment: I was having the same issue.. Try this out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929979/firebase-remote-notifications-not-receiving

Answer (score 11):

set the following code in AppDelegate.m

```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    // for development 
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];

    // for production 
   //     [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];


    }
```

Comment: Hi Alaa, welcome to StackOverflow. I've suggested an edit to your answer to add in code formatting (4 indented spaces) to make it easier to read. Would you mind also editing your answer to explain _why_ this solves the problem? Thank you!

Comment: If the token type is set to FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeUnknown InstanceID will read the provisioning profile to find out the token type. From the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/interface_f_i_r_instance_i_d#a7cd9dde64e899e05a27397d3ee3fb398

Comment: you saved my day man, I was struggling why my notification was not working in background mode, but after adding this it started working. But this was not found in firebase messaging https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/FCM/AppDelegate.m  sample code which is strange

Comment: I integrate this code but not working.when i send message from firebase console and add device token i am getting error Invalid registration token. Check the token format.

Comment: `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox`  is `The APNS token type for the app. If the token type is set to UNKNOWN InstanceID will implicitly try to figure out what the actual token type is from the provisioning profile.` I got that problem when using Match

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your app is in the foreground when testing. When your app is in the foreground no visible notification is triggered, instead you receive the callback to `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-audience#receive_and_handle_notifications) for more info.

To verify, put your app in the background and try sending the push notification again.

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify. When the app goes into background, during first 30 seconds it isn't fall asleep yet, so for this reason I still get didReceiveRemoteNotification calls. After no calls.

Comment: Ah in that case I agree my answer will not help and I'm not sure what the problem might be. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I have same configuration you have and it works like AdamK said. (While in background mode, notification appears.)  Also check your certificates.

Comment: Check this video,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpbNFIY1qJ0   time 13:45.    They said that if you set  Info.plist FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO  you should call  "setAPNSToken"  and  "appDidReceiveMessage"

Answer (score 0):

First check with Firebase Notification Console to see if the notification is sending or not. If it is success, then the problem is in the code side; otherwise, check what error is coming in Firebase. If you receive error message as APNs missing, you need to check with development/production .p12 file in Project Setting->Cloud Messaging tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function in your app delegate sandbox for development prod for prodction

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Are you using https://pushtry.com for test the FCM notification**? **then don't use** because I have lots of issue with this website for testing notification some time it working and some times not. it's not giving consistence result and it may be effect in FCM flow and totally block the receiving notifications.

**I recommended to use https://fcm.snayak.dev for test the notification.**