# FCM notification is not working in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am integrating FCM notification and cloud messaging in my app. I have followed exactly same steps mentioned in Firebase doc. Even I have tried with sample code given by FCM. It is just throwing some warnings as:

`<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. and <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging registration is not ready with auth credentials.`

My code written in Appdelegate.m is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Register for remote notifications
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }

    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}

// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

    // Pring full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];

    // TODO: If necessary send token to appliation server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
}

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]
```

Comment: How are you sending the messages? Are you using the firebase console and targeting all devices? Did you add GoogleService-Info.plist?

You can also try implementing application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError for more info

Comment: I am sending messaging through firebase console (notification) and i have added googleService-Info.plist. didFailtoRegister is not getting called. i am getting device token but no notification on device

Comment: and yaa,  i am targeting to single device and also put FCM registration token in required field. In firebase console, status of message is completed but no push notification on device. i have checked with both state i.e. having app in background and foreground as well.

Comment: The code looks correct. You should see Connected to FCM when your app goes active, and if you re-install your app you should get the latest token, though it doesn't matter since you can target all app users from the firebase console. I'd be sure to double check that you have your provisioning profile set up correctly as well as your certs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs#create_an_app_id

I can't really post an answer since I'm also setting this up, and I got lucky with it just working. There isn't much debug info available either :(

Comment: it is giving messages "Connected to FCM" but no notification and i have followed the same doc :(

Comment: Chris one query, are u using paid version?? I am working with free one (spark)

Comment: Yea, this is on Blaze

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to have the "priority" set to "high" if you want the notification to get displayed while the app is in the background:

[Firebase IOS push notification doesn't work when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830621/firebase-ios-push-notification-doest-not-work-when-app-is-closed/38093488#38093488)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same thing with my iOS app. FCM and GCM DO NOT WORK with iOS. No matter what anyone says there is no chance that it will work. I spend 2 weeks and went everywhere on the net asking and looking a post. iOS will only accept APNS push notification . Save your self the headache and start with apps.

EDIT:
Here is the newest repository for FCM. Give this a shot and see what comes of it.
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios
It seems a little different than the one I tried when I was working on my iOS version. 
@Chris, is this the code branch that you used to implement your version?

Comment: FCM delegates to APNS if the app is inactive. I've successfully sent a push notification from the firebase console to my iphone (simulator doesn't support push notifications)

Comment: Are you using the APNS number or are your using the GCM/FCM device token.

Comment: Because if you just using GCM then please make a full tutorial with step by step process to perform this because I would like to know how to do it

Comment: Even i would also like to know. i have worked with GCM and FCM since 1 week but none of them worked for me. Please share some code or some thing helpful so that i can proceed with it further. Please reply soon @chris.

Comment: @MNM I'm not 100% there yet (I can't yet trigger a PN from my own server) but I'm pretty close. I'm able to send messages from the firebase console both when my app is closed and open, and from my server when my app is open. I just followed the official guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Comment: @Chris yeah thats how you send a pn with apns. I have that done and over with. I still can't send GCM using this. The code that google provides only gives the token for GCM not the APNS token. And GCM will not use the APNS token to send pn. And iOS will not accept anything but APNS tokens.

Comment: @MNM Hmm... I haven't used APNS directly at all. I've only used FCM to send messages from console.firebase.google.com using the Notification tool. I also don't touch my APNS token either, the firebase library swizzles the app delegate and associates it with the firebase device token, which I use to target within firebase console. As I understand, behind the scenes, firebase delegates to GCM which delegates to APNS

Comment: @Chris yes that is how it is suppose to work. But I have had all sorts of issues getting to send the pn. Thats very interesting that you can get it to send. How is your build set up in Xcode? and could you tell us which version of Xcode and iOS you are using

Comment: @Chris I am going over the FCM and I would like to know what is the format of the token that you get back when you register for the service. Like what format is it in. HexCode like this 13596673c79ed4d340c208bd994bc954ee1bac64c90701e6088122be17f6ebr5     or in GCM type code like this    fz-Z4ZLSgoU:APA91bFQ3Owt9as73GAZKJy0m5TmAa3OncaOcBoYSDSXdqR0nGsoOWHyky_N1IU14lD73QEPziqsbpu6otmLwzPGHOAukuN_Bw8xuY7ISWcn6eCuMgCkqNuK5I2fF7Kshowjox8RG-7S

Comment: @MNM latest iOS and XCode 7.3.1, Firebase from cocoapods (Firebase/Messaging (3.2.0) and FirebaseMessaging (1.1.0)). My GCM token looks like the latter (fz-Z4Z...). That's what I address my message to (though in the firebase console you can just blast it to all devices, so I did that initially to reduce the number of things that could go wrong)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113686/discussion-between-chris-and-mnm).

Comment: Chris one query, are u using paid version?? I am working with free one (spark)

Comment: Guys, I have read the discussion but cannot seem to be able to access the chat. Can you tell what's the final decision then? FCM on iOS, yay or nay?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having same kind of issue. I get "Connected to FCM" message and token and seems everything integrated perfectly, yet unable to receive any notification.

However, I received notification at once but then after without any code change and certificate changes or removal, I am unable to receive any further notifications.

Check my code here, it's a cocos2d app.

```
func didLoadFromCCB()
    {
    ...
    setupPushNotification()
}

func setupPushNotification () {
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

        // Register for remote notifications
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            // Fallback
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }

        FIRApp.configure()

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "tokenRefreshNotification:",
            name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didBecomeActive:", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didEnterBackground:", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    }


// [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

func didBecomeActive(application:UIApplication) {
        NSLog("Did Become Active")
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func didEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        NSLog("Did enter background")
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        NSLog("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
}
```

I don't know how I got that only one correct notification then it turned tables. :(

Let me know how to resolve this.,

Comment: Put this in another question not here

Answer (score 0):

try sending this

```
curl --header "Authorization: key={YOUR_API_KEY}" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"{YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN}\",\"content_available\":true,\"priority\":\"high\",\"notification\":{\"title\":\"TEST\",\"sound\":\"default\",\"body\":\"IT WORKS!\",\"badge\":1}}"
```

It works for me. (Obviously, register for push notifications first then print out the device token)