# Firebase IOS push notification doesn't work when app is closed

Tags: ios, firebase

Firebase IOS push notification doest not work when app is closed. I have followed all the steps as in documentation

Comment: Describe your Error ? and  what u want ? and what is your code ?

Answer (score 9):

It's a quick fix, simply add "priority": "high" in your payload next to "notification" etc. and the iOS Notification will work when the app is in the background.

So this will work:

```
"to":"TOKEN ID",
"notification" : {
  "body" : "test"
},
"priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: I'm stuck in a similar issue, I'm sending data notification instead of normal push notifications and can not receive data from notifications when the app is closed (not even running in background). Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply adding `title` to the `notification` like this:

```
"notification" : {
  "title": "foo",
  "body" : "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this, hope it works:

```
POST https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
{
    "to": "TOKEN_ID",
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "title": "foo",
        "body": "bar"
    }
}
```